# How to get the time that has passed since an element was uploaded?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, date

I need to know the time passed since an element was uploaded to the server, for instance:

- I uploaded an element yesterday, and I want to show in php the time that has passed from the upload date to the current date.

I'm not sure to figure out what is the best way to achieve this, not sure if I need a view with the calculated date or add a new field on my table

If needed, here there is a summary of how my table looks in PostgreSQL:

```
id | user_id | title | upload_date
```

Any suggestions to clear my mind are very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: when you insert the element into the database, simply put [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) for the `upload_date` and then when you want to see the difference in time, just use `time()-upload_date`.

Comment: im mysql i would use DATEDIFF(), i would suppose  PostgreSQL has something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostreSQL, you could simply do `SELECT age(now(), "upload_date")`, or even simply `age("upload_date")` should give you the interval between the date, and current timestamp.
Bookmark [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks, so now I have the time that I need, but, how could I implement this within an MVC framework? I have in the model a function which make the select age("upload_date") and return the values of that select, the controller stores that values in a variable and pass it to the view, where I have a foreach for retrieve the data stored in database of every element and show it, but how I retrieve the calculated date value of the elements if the value is not being stored. I hope I explained well.

Comment: @Apprectice: Why have a method `getAge()` that queries along the lines of `SELECT age("upload_date") as uploaded FROM tbl WHERE "id" = ?`, get the id from the model if required...

Comment: @Apprentice: How and where this method belongs in your code is up to you. If you follow the MVC pattern then somewhere in the Model layer is the right place, obviously. But I don't know which framework you're using, nor how your model layer looks like. That's an entirely different question, to be honest

Comment: You are right and sorry for that, I was very confused, thanks for the useful information and for clear out my mind.